# Reuse file path in Jekyll

Tags: jekyll, liquid

I am very new to writing websites and jekyll so I apologize if my terminology is unclear or wrong.

I have a bunch of saved files (foo1, foo2, etc) in a subdirectory called 'savedfiles' of my root jekyll folder. Suppose I am editing index.md which is in a sub folder called 'subfolder" and want to link to each of these. One way I can do this is to use

```
{{ site.url }}/savedfiles/foo1
{{ site.url }}/savedfiles/foo2
etc
```

Is there a way of saving the file path in a variable say pathfoo so that I could write

```
{{ pathfoo }}/foo1
etc
```

And sort of related to this can I get the file path of the subfolder that index.md is in? I know that

```
{{ page.path }}
```

will give me {{ site.url }}/subfolder/index.md but I want {{ site.url }}/subfolder. Is this possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Saving a path in a variable

```
{% capture path %}{{ site.url }}{{ site.baseurl}}/savedfiles/{% endcapture %}
```

you can now use this variable like this :

```
<a href="{{ path }}foo.html">Link to foo</a>
```

### Getting file path from a file

It is a little bit tricky. But here is a way :

```
{% assign pathParts = page.path | split: "/" %}
{% assign length = pathParts.size | minus: 2 %}
{% assign path = "" %}
{% for c in (0..length) %}
    {% capture path %}{{ path }}/{{pathParts[c]}}{% endcapture %}
{% endfor %}
```

You now have a `path` variable like `/folder/subfolder`. This could be simplest with `pop` or `shift` filters, but they are not working as expected and will change in Jekyll 3.0.